# FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token is depricated and returns null in Xamarin.Android using Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a Xamarin.Android project using [Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging v71.1740](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/71.1740.0) nuget plugin,

I'm trying to get the FCM Token that was already generated in the `FirebaseMessagingService` extended class method,

```
public override void OnNewToken(string p0)
{
    base.OnNewToken(p0);

    // use token
}
```

using,

```
var token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
```

But this returns `null` and it listed as obsolete too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE**

`GetInstanceId<InstanceIdResult>()` is also [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-taskinstanceidresult-getinstanceid) in favour of `FirebaseMessaging.getToken()` for **FCM Token** and `FirebaseInstallations.getId()` for **Instance Identifier**,

[image]

So, [FirebaseMessaging.getToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#public-taskstring-gettoken) is the recommended way now to get the **FCM Token**,

This is how you can consume it easily,

```
var token = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
```

and [FirebaseInstallations.getId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/installations/FirebaseInstallations#public-taskstring-getid) is the recommended way now to get the **Instance Identifier**,

This is how you can consume it easily,

```
var id = await FirebaseInstallations.Instance.GetId();
```

> here, `var` is of the `Type` `Java.Lang.Object`. Do, `token.ToString()` to get the `string` value.

**ORIGINAL**

`FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` is [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-string-gettoken) in favour of `GetInstanceId<InstanceIdResult>()`,

[image]

So, [GetInstanceId<InstanceIdResult>()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-taskinstanceidresult-getinstanceid) is the recommended way,

This is how you can consume it,

```
var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>();
var token = instanceIdResult.Token;
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution, but FirebaseInstanceId.Instance is null in my Xamarin Android app... do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: assuming you have done the basic configurations correct, did you run a clean & rebuild after adding google-services.json file and setting it as a GoogleServicesJson?

Comment: by basic setups what I meant was,

* install `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` plugin in the Xamarin.Android project
* include the google-services.json file in the android project root and set its build action `GoogleServicesJson`
* add, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the AndroidManifest.xml
* make sure Google Play Services are available in the Android phone you're testing
* create a notification channel if above android 8
* create a FirebaseMessagingService Service with `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT` IntentFilter

Comment: Yes... all seems ok. Are you using in your project Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics? Thank you for your patience!

Comment: no, I'm not... can you share an example codebase? or I'll share you one tomorrow, so you can check if the issue exists in that 

Comment: Thank you very much! My project is a little big... I was able to retrieve token with the deprecated method FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token but now, I don't now why, FirebaseInstanceId.Instance is null :(

Comment: Please, can you share me your Android NuGet packages list?

Comment: can you please check your plugin in this project? https://github.com/rizanzaky/XamPlayfield/tree/plays/firebasepush/XamPlayfield

Comment: Thank you! I've downgraded some dependencies of my project and start using the same Xamarin.Forms version as in your demo (4.3.0.908675) and now I can retrieve token with the deprecated method FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token (FirebaseInstanceId.Instance is not null anymore). I'm still looking for an official (non-obsolete) Xamarin guide for getting push tokens!

Comment: So what about `var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>();`
`var token = instanceIdResult.Token;`, I hope you can use it now

Comment: Your method for retrieve token works... and it is not deprecated!

Comment: Finally, I've found the problem... using last version of Xamarin.Firebase.Core (71.1601.0) make my FirebaseInstanceId.Instance null

Comment: better report it 

Comment: @marcogramy - have they fixed that?

Comment: @RizanZaky Used the solution you provided, I am getting compiler error  'Task<IInstanceIdResult>' does not contain a definition for 'Token' and no accessible extension method 'Token' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IInstanceIdResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I have the latest Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging update installed. Is there anything else I need?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this solution is also deprecated now.

Comment: @c.lamont.dev And the relevant (Android) docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-taskinstanceidresult-getinstanceid-

Comment: You need `using Android.Gms.Extensions;` to be able to `await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();`
Also `token` is of type `Java.Lang.Object`, call `ToString()` to get a .NET string

Answer (score 4):

Oh look, `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance` is [deprecated too](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-taskinstanceidresult-getinstanceid-).

Looks like the more newer way is:

```
var token = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting null on `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance`, when calling

```
var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>();
```

I have to update

```
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging to version 71.1740.1
```

And add this to yourproject.android.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <AndroidManifestMerger>manifestmerger.jar</AndroidManifestMerger> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

[(more info)](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/192#issuecomment-629481418)

This works for me (not sure if both are mandatory)